# ReactJS Broken Line in Apple Safari

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a problem on my `` <div className={`${classes.center} ${classes.or}`}>OR</div> ``.
It seems thats it problem on Apple Safari only. The right line there seems broken. It works on Google Chrome and other browsers. I'm using Safari Version 12

Pls check this CodeSandbox link [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/login-forked-pe7ee?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/index.js:2464-2523)

[image]

```css
or: {
  position: "relative",
  marginBottom: "10px",
  "&:before, &:after": {
    content: "''",
    display: "inline-block",
    height: "1px",
    width: "40%",
    background: "#00000044",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%"
  },
  "&:before": {
    transform: "translate(-70%, -50%)"
  },
  "&:after": {
    transform: "translate(70%, -50%)"
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't even say what the problem is.

Comment: @SamR. I did. The `<div className={`${classes.center} ${classes.or}`}>OR</div>` is broken on Apply Safari

Comment: Not on my Safari. You better post a screenshot and include the Safari version.

Comment: Specify a `x` position for `position: absolute`, Add `left: "30%"` to `"&:before, &:after"`.

Comment: I've had multiple issues in various browsers with using % in height and width. Have you tried setting `width: "40%"` to an arbitrary pixel value instead?

Comment: @BaconPancakes. what would the ideal arbitrary value to put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css `transform` is causing the issue here. Instead of the, use `left: 0` for `before` and `right: 0` for `after` and it should work fine. It will make sure that both the pseudo elements stick to the respective ends and since they have same width, the UI will auto adjust.

```css
or: {
  position: "relative",
  marginBottom: "10px",
  "&:before, &:after": {
    content: "''",
    display: "inline-block",
    height: "1px",
    width: "40%",
    background: "#00000044",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%"
  },
  "&:before": {
    left: 0
  },
  "&:after": {
    right: 0
  }
}
```

Fix sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/login-forked-4cbvm?file=/src/index.js

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.